# mysql query not like several text matches

Tags: mysql

I am trying to do a simple query that has a where clause stating there is no match for 2 items:

```
where l.country not like \"%USA%\" or \"%CA%\" ORDER BY l.state
```

I also tried:

```
where l.country not like \"%USA%\" or l.country not like \"%CA%\" ORDER BY l.state
```

also tried:

```
where l.country not like (\"%USA%\", \"%CA%\") ORDER BY l.state
```

is there a way to use "not like" with more than one match?

Comment: Yes but it's regex based slower approach. What's wrong with the current one

Comment: What is your actually logic?  Do you want to match records which don't have USA _and_ CA, or USA _or_ CA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your original condition:

```
where l.country not like "%USA%" or "%CA%" ORDER BY l.state
```

I assume you intend this to mean "the country is neither the USA nor CA."

If so, you would write it this way:

```
where l.country not like '%USA%' and l.country not like '%CA%' ORDER BY l.state
```

But there's no syntax in SQL for `NOT LIKE 'X' OR 'Y'`. The `LIKE` predicate has a left operand and a single right operand, no more.

The expression you wrote is a valid expression, but doesn't do what you think it does. It's like as if you had written this:

```
where (l.country not like "%USA%") or ("%CA%") ORDER BY l.state
```

That is, two terms, separated by `OR`, the first is a `LIKE` comparison, and the second is just a single string literal on its own. That's a valid term in an expression, but it doesn't do anything useful. It's like writing:

```
x = 6 * 8 + 0
```

What effect does the zero have in that expression? None.

---

Update: I was mistaken, I overlooked one effect of the query as you wrote it. You should know that in a boolean expression if you `OR` two terms, it doesn't matter what the first term is if the second term is always TRUE.

```
WHERE (some expression) OR (TRUE)
```

This is always true.

The literal string `'%CA%'` counts as true, because it's not an empty string or a NULL. So in your original query, the WHERE clause is always true no matter what the country is.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `REGEXP` with an alternation:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE country NOT REGEXP '"%USA%"|"%CA%"'
```

**Notes:**

You don't need to escape double quotes which appear inside of string literals in single quotes.  Your original query would not run, I think, because you need to compare a column using `LIKE` against either another column or a string literal, normally in single quotes.

`REGEXP` is not case sensitive, so we could have used `usa` and `ca` for the same result, though this does not appear to matter in your case.